# Multi auth Laravel 5.4 - "Route [admin-login] not defined"

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Hello everyone hope you can help me.

I've been trying to make a multi auth app with the new version of laravel 5.4, where i have a user form for sign in and sign up, and another form for the admin users.

After creating the first controller for my Admin sign in page the error on the title comes by going to the route: `http://localhost:8000/admin_login`

**This are my routes created from the console: php artisan route:list**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('admin_login', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('admin_login', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('admin_logout', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@logout');
Route::post('admin_password/email', 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('admin_password/reset', 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('admin_password/reset', 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
Route::get('admin_password/reset/{token}', 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::get('admin_register', 'AdminAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('admin_register', 'AdminAuth\RegisterController@register');


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/admin_home', 'AdminHomeController@index');
```

**This is my LoginController from AdminAuth:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin-auth.login');
    }
}
```

**And this is my login view from admin:**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login Admin</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin_login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('admin_password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you defined a route without a name. So in login view from admin
replace

```
action="{{ route('admin_login') }}"
```

with

```
action="{{ url('admin_login') }}"
```

Same thing for other routes.

I also was solving multi auth task, so think you may even add routes like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Auth::routes();    
});
```

Hope this helps!